# Given a multi-group pattern, how do you split a string on a specific group in that pattern?

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I have this pattern that I want to use to split a vector: `"([^ ])(,)([^ ])"`. But the vector should be split on the second group `(,)` leaving the first and the third with the first item and the second item respectively.

I tried to add the non-capturing pattern `?:` but it doesn't seem to work.

```r
my_string <- 
  "FIRST item,SECOND, item,third ITEM,FOURTH item"

strsplit(my_string, "(?:[^ ])(,)(?:[^ ])")[[1]]
```

I get `"FIRST ite"  "ECOND, ite" "hird ITE"   "OURTH item"` will I need a pattern to get `"FIRST item"  "SECOND, item" "third ITEM"   "FOURTH item"`.

Comment: `SECOND, item` <-- is the comma after `SECOND` a typo?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I want to split the string only on the comma that is preceded and followed by a non-space character.

Comment: @ggorlen Perl-compatible regexps are available in R.'

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using

```r
stringr::str_split(my_string, "(?<=[^ ])(,)(?=[^ ])")
```

Comment: This coincidentally works for the particular input you showed us, but it would fail should the real data have spaces surrounding commas which you don't expect.

Comment: @Tim. Yeah, I don't want to capture commas surrounded by spaces.

Comment: @CptNemo You can still use the base R `strsplit` with a pattern containing lookarounds, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406758/3832970). BTW, `stringr` does not use PCRE, it uses ICU regex engine, while you tagged the question with `pcre` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You may still use the base R `strsplit` function, but with a `perl=TRUE` argument to enable the PCRE rege engine and use *lookarounds* instead of consuming *non-capturing* groups in the pattern to check for non-whitespace characters around `,`:

```
my_string <- "FIRST item,SECOND, item,third ITEM,FOURTH item"
strsplit(my_string, "(?<=\\S),(?=\\S)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
## =>[1] "FIRST item"   "SECOND, item" "third ITEM"   "FOURTH item"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/FDkzpP) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rwvZg4/2). Details:

- `(?<=\S)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a non-whitespace char immediately before the current location
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires a non-whitespace char immediately after the current location.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a complicated regex. Here's a simple regex that will work: `,(?=[a-zA-Z])`.

An explanation:

- `,`: Match commas
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])`: but only the ones followed by letters a through z **case insensitive**.

```r
my_string <- "FIRST item,SECOND, item,third ITEM,FOURTH item"
strsplit(my_string, ",(?=[a-zA-Z])", perl = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "FIRST item"   "SECOND, item" "third ITEM"   "FOURTH item"
stringr::str_split(my_string, ",(?=[a-zA-Z])")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "FIRST item"   "SECOND, item" "third ITEM"   "FOURTH item"
```